# Accessing server through web browser using ip address redirects to localhost

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop

I'm using `prestashop` to set up an e-commerce website on my cloud server. I was able to successfully install it on the server and it works fine on the server locally, i.e. if I look at the website using localhost on the server. However when I try to access it from a different machine it won't work because, it gets redirected to `localhost/index.php?` I'm not sure what could be wrong or even where to start looking... any help would be appreciated. Only thing I could think of was the `index.php` file. It has following 2 lines of code and is generated by `prestashop`.

I apologize if this is not the correct SO website, as I wasn't sure what the issue could be related to.

Thank you.

Comment: at a guess "localhost" has been hard coded somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When moving an CMS to another domain problems like this often occurs. Most CMS saves the domain they should run on in configuration file oder database. If there is an request for another domain they are sending an redirect (HTTP state code 302) back. I think problem here is that this one is set to localhost.

A short search on google pointed out that prestashop saves a domain name configuration in a mySQL database. Since petrashop 1.5 it should be in a table called `PREFIX_shop_url`. Before it was saved in `PREFIX_configuration` as `PREFIX_shop_url`. But I didn't tested on my own. You should have a look on your own and change the value in database to your new domain.

You could use [mysql command line client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html) to connect to database and change the value. If your are not so familiar with SQL you could also use a GUI like [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php).

Comment: I was trying to install CMS by remotely accessing the server, hence, using localhost. I tried installing it by accessing it using the IP and I was able to install it successfully and access it using IP. So it seems like, as you said, prestashop saves the current domain while installation and can be only accessed using the same domain. Thank you!